# auto post fb app is posting as a page on wrong timeline

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the following code to auto post on 3 facebook pages for which I am the admin. The page name is passed to a code that fetches the token and page id from DB and this gets passed to the code below -

```
$params = array(
  // this is the main access token (facebook profile)
  "access_token" => $fb_page_arr['access_token'],
  "message" => $status,
  "link" => $link,
  "picture" => $image,
  "name" => $link_title,
  "caption" => $link_caption,
  "description" => $link_desc
  );


try {
  $ret = $fb->api('/'.$fb_page_arr['page_id'].'/feed', 'POST', $params);
} catch(Exception $e) {
  mailAdmin($e->getMessage(),FALSE);
}
```

This code works via CURL in PHP. On PAGE A B C the following is noticed -

> FB PAGE A - Correct Output
>
> FB PAGE B - Correct Output
>
> FB PAGE C - NO POST, and also there is NO ERROR. However the following is observed when debugged "story": "'FB PAGE C posted a link to School's timeline."

What is "School"? I am not posting anything to School

Now I have noticed that "school" is a category of Page C, is it using that?

How can I make it to work for Page C also?

My tokens and page id are all verified and working.

The json dump for the PAGE C looks like this

```
"data": [
{
     "category": "School",
     "category_list": [
        {
           "id": "36518249351xxxx",
           "name": "School"
        }
     ],
     "name": "PAGE C",
     "access_token": "alskdjlaksjdlksjdlak",
     "perms": [
        "ADMINISTER",
        "EDIT_PROFILE",
        "CREATE_CONTENT",
        "MODERATE_CONTENT",
        "CREATE_ADS",
        "BASIC_ADMIN"
     ],
     "id": "1622434xxxxxxxx"
  }
```

Comment: How do you iterate over the DB results? There's no array index shown in the code...

Comment: Tobi thanks for looking into my problem. I dont iterate. CURL calls this script asynchronously each time there is a call to update a PAGE. So there is no loop. This code runs for one page update only. The only time we use a DB is to fetch that PAGE_NAME's accesstoken and page_id into $fb_page_arr[]